# Как достать из строки все до :

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть txt файл с подобным содержанием

```
Taichtamuu:z5US6pqrGiH7Mh:Lafapone1992@rambler.ru
Keaksagimi:jMMZwDViXa85XtG:Vebnapno1995@rambler.ru
Liepnalot:gsUvuXcatlVoR:Kosamnanel2001@rambler.ru
Gevimnyuov:rlnYyvEk6kLthA:Luteltabi2005@rambler.ru
Siihzidari:pS8HvYg6lQUcp:Levabaane1990@rambler.ru
Keebapitn:VVHW3MD9oX4u7ox:Nezasol1988@rambler.ru
```

нужно из этого создать 3 списка с вот таким содержанием

```
1 список ["Taichtamuu", "Keaksagimi", "Liepnalot", "Gevimnyuov", "Siihzidari", "Keebapitn"]
2 список ["z5US6pqrGiH7Mh", "jMMZwDViXa85XtG", "gsUvuXcatlVoR", "rlnYyvEk6kLthA", "pS8HvYg6lQUcp", "VVHW3MD9oX4u7ox"]
3 список ["Lafapone1992@rambler.ru", "Vebnapno1995@rambler.ru", "Kosamnanel2001@rambler.ru", "Luteltabi2005@rambler.ru", "Levabaane1990@rambler.ru", "Nezasol1988@rambler.ru"]
```

Как это сделать

Comment: Читаете построчно, split по ":", первый элемент аппенд в первый список, второй - во второй, третий, соответственно, в третий... Добавьте в вопрос свой код и с чем сложности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `циклов` и `split'ов`.

```
user_names = [] # Создаем список для юзернеймов

passwords = [] # Для паролей

mails = [] # Для почт

with open('somr_file', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file: # Открываем нужный файл 
    input_data = input_file.read().split('\n') # Читаем его и делим на строки.

    for line in input_data:
        splitted_line = line.split(':') # Делим строку по знаку ':'
        user_names.append(splitted_line[0])
        passwords.append(splitted_line[1])
        mails.append(splitted_line[2])
        # Добавляем 1 полученное слово после деление в список user_names, 2 - в passwords, 3 - в mails.

print(user_names)
print(passwords)
print(mails)

#Выводим на экран.
```

Comment: Желательно закрыть файл ещё.

Comment: @nomnoms12, Точно, спасибо, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: а файл, все же, лучше открывать через with open, менеджер контекста: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#opening-and-closing-a-file-in-python

Comment: @Jack_oS понял, прочитал, поправлю.